# Problem with mariaDB, HSF+ and Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: web-server, hard-drive, mariadb

I'm making a full LAMP using a Raspberry PI 4 w/ 4GB RAM, Apachie2, MariaDB 10.3.22 and PHP and a 4 Teribite HSF+ USB drive. Initial setup worked fine till I attempted to change to data store of mariaDB to the HSF+ data directory. Yes, I installed HSF functions and samba. Both in the GUI and command line have no problems with access the drives folders and files.

In mariadb.cnf I changed:

```
datadir = /mnt/LaCie/Shared/RasDBdata
```

Starting mariaDB fails and in `journalctl -xe` i get:

```
May 27 09:07:06 raspberrypi mysqld[13358]: 2020-05-27  9:07:06 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 13358 ...
May 27 09:07:06 raspberrypi mysqld[13358]: 2020-05-27  9:07:06 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /mnt/LaCie/Shared/RasDBdata/ is case insensitive
May 27 09:07:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

As you can see by the path I am using case sensitive names. How can I make mariadb or is it raspbian to know it is case sensitive?

Comment: Use a Linux supported filesystem like EXT4, reiser, btrfs, F2FS rather than the tragically unsupported HFS.

Comment: Dougie's right.  By my reading [of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Other_operating_systems), people likely stopped trying to reverse engineer it after Paragon released proprietary drivers -- which almost certainly will never be compiled for the Pi, and they and Apple will never provide the source code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with MariaDB, but it's error message indicates that it uses case sensitive filenames and your filesystem does not support it. I suppose you are using a **fat** formated filesystem that uses case insensitive filenames. So you should either configure MariaDB to use case insensitive filenames (don't know if it is possible, look at the manual), or you use a case sensitive filesystem. The best choice would be to format the filesystem with **ext4** because it is Raspbians default.